# Shuffling multidimensional array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, multidimensional-array, p5.js

This function shuffles only matrix[y], but I want it to shuffle matrix[y][x] But it doesn't want to shuffle correctly.

The code what I used:

```
function Shuffle(arguments) {
    for (var k = 0; k < arguments.length; k++) {
        var i = arguments[k].length;
        if (i == 0)
            return false;
        else {
            while (--i) {
                var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                var tempi = arguments[k][i];
                var tempj = arguments[k][j];
                arguments[k][i] = tempj;
                arguments[k][j] = tempi;
            }
            return arguments;
        }
    }
    return arguments
}

var matrix = [

];

var ab = 36;

for (var y = 0; y < ab; y++) {
    matrix.push([])
    for (var x = 0; x < ab; x++) {
        matrix[y][x] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < ab / 2; x++) {
        matrix[y][x] = 1
    }
}


arr = Shuffle(matrix);

console.log(arr)
var side = 16;

function setup() {

    createCanvas(arr[0].length * side, arr.length * side);
    background('#acacac');
    frameRate()

}

function draw() {
    for (var y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < arr[y].length; x++) {

            if (matrix[y][x] == 0) {
                fill(0, 255, 0)
                rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
            } else if (matrix[y][x] == 1) {
                fill("red")
                rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
            } else if (matrix[y][x] == 2) {
                fill(255, 255, 0)
                rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
            } else if (matrix[y][x] == 3) {
                fill(255, 0, 0)
                rect(y * side, x * side, side, side)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this function shuffles only matrix[y], but I want it to shuffle matrix[y][x].
Any ideas? Here is the screenshot:

[image].

Comment: shuffle row first then column, or merge it into 1 dimension array shuffle then split back

Comment: Well i'm not so good with arrays

Comment: i the problem is youre returning after the while loop, so the for loop doesnt finish like its suppose to

Comment: so how can i do that ?

Comment: just remove the return arguments; after while loop

Comment: OMGGG It worked THANK YOU MAN!!!!!!

Comment: @ChrisLi You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I forgot to post an answer, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you had a return statement after the whileloop, causing the forloop to never finish as expected

```
function Shuffle(arguments) {
    for (var k = 0; k < arguments.length; k++) {
        var i = arguments[k].length;
        if (i == 0)
            return false;
        else {
            while (--i) {
                var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                var tempi = arguments[k][i];
                var tempj = arguments[k][j];
                arguments[k][i] = tempj;
                arguments[k][j] = tempi;
            }
            return arguments; // remove this line
        }
    }
    return arguments
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can transform this to a one dimensional array, then shuffle, then transform back. You just need to know how many rows you want.

```
const myArr = [[1,2],[3,4]];
const oneDimArr = myArr.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
const shuffledArr = Shuffle(oneDimArr); // this is your existing function
const shuffled2DimArr = shuffledArr.reduce((acc, i) => {
  if(acc[acc.length-1].length >= 2) { // here we build 2 cols
    acc.push([]);
  }
  acc[acc.length-1].push(i);
  return acc;
}, [[]]);
```